# How to add a line and remove it; add another line and remove it; and so on in a R plot?

Tags: r, graph

I am trying to show a group of audience a set of time series data. The R codes below allow me to add a line at a time. But after a while, there are simply too many lines on the plot to see anything. Ideally I want to add a line and then remove it; add another line and remove it and so on until each column is shown. Is there a straightforward way to modify my commands to achieve this goal, please? Thank you!

By the way, as further improvement, can I also show its legend every time I show a line. For example, when I show the first line I also show it is for USA; when I show the second I also show it is for the UK; etc. Thank you again!

```
matplot(1957:2006, Xt.model3f, type="n", xlab="Year", ylab="Xt")

for(i in 1:ncol(Xt.model3f)){
  for(j in 1:10^7){}
  lines(1957:2006, Xt.model3f[, i])
}
```

Comment: I don't know any way to unplot, other than plotting the line again in the background color (and this may leave weird visual artifacts).

Comment: You might be able to do something clever with (Shiny)[http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/], for example setting the transparency to 0 for all columns that are currently not selected.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will try and post update if I find anything good.

Comment: Josilber is right, you can't unplot using R. You have to redraw the whole image, without the offending line.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks! Then what software or language can do that relatively easily, please? I am sure I have seen such effect numerous times before. It is kind like some animation, right?

Comment: R generates plots very quickly, so just re-plot with the new data.  If you want to "animate", you can save all the plots as GIFs, combine them, and use any app which supports animated GIFs to display.

Comment: Have you tried JQuery?